# Insert Spark DF as column in existing hive table

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to append a column spark DF to an existing Hive table, I'm using the code below to overwrite the table but only works when df schema and hive table schema are equal, but sometimes I need to add one column and since schemas don't match it does not work.
Is there a way to append the df as a column?

Or I have to make an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN in a spark.sql()?

```
temp = spark.table('temp')
temp.write.mode('overwrite').insertInto(datalab + '.' + table,overwrite=True)
```

Hope my question is understandable, thanks.

Comment: why don't you use `saveAsTable` instead of `insertInto`? `temp.write.saveAsTable(f"{datalab}.{table}", mode="overwrite")`

Comment: with `overwrite=True`, do you really mean you want to overwrite `temp` table?

Comment: SaveAsTable has been showing this error that I was only able to avoid by using insertInto and Alter Table: "Can not create the managed table('`db`.`table`'). The associated location('hdfs://path/table') already exists.;"

Comment: by overwrite I mean I want to overwrite the hive table with my current df because it needs to be saved with the same name and the content has changed

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dataframe with new set of data that has additional columns, then append that to the existing table, in the following manner.

```
new_data_df = df with additional columns   
new_data_df.write.mode('append').saveAsTable('same_table_name', mergeSchema=True)
```

So suppose, the new column you have added is 'column_new', the older records in the table will have been set with null values.